# Vanilla javascript to a vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to implement a audio player with subtitle synchronization in my vue app.

I found a pen by [@Musixmatch](https://codepen.io/jewel998/pen/GRRPExw?editors=1010) which does the work.

However, its all vanilla.

In my vue app, I created a `lyric.js` file which contains the js code enclosed by:

```
export const initAudioSub = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        ....the vanillajs code here...
    })
}
```

Now in my component.vue, I imported it like this `import { initAudioSub } from './lyric.js'`
and called the `initAUdioSub` in the mounted hook like this `mounted() { initAudioSub(); }`

but I get an error saying :

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at eval (lyric.js?6080:4)
```

Am I even close? can someone enlighten me on how to do it?

Comment: `$` is apparently a jQuery alias there. You need to make sure it's added on the project as well.

Comment: @YomS. Should I add it on `index.html`?

Comment: @YomS. Thanks man, I got it. :)